# AppBar reusable in different pages and route on different page effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I cannot solve two issues with my reusable appbar.

1. Appbar has not the same width of the page.
   [Appbar shorter then page width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyWrm.png)
2. Text and Icons seems not centered vertically. It looks like the appbar had a border! (if i Move alignment I can seed the border. See picture 2.
   [see white icon on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrHvX.png)
3. When I cange page, It seems that an Appbar Is under The reusable Appbar. See picture 3.
   [Appbar under reusable Appbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKn9m.png)

In every page I use this code to call the Appbar:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: ReusableBar(),
      ),
```

This is the code of the reusable AppBar:

```
class ReusableBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //number = number + displayedText;
    return AppBar(
      //elevation: 0.0,
      centerTitle: true,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      titleSpacing: 0.0,
      title: Text(getTranslated(context, 'total_click:') + "$_appbarcounter"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, -4.0),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.save,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // do something
            //TODO AGGIUNGERE FUNZIONE AL PULSANTE SAVE CON PAGINA DI SALVATAGGIO
          },
        )
      ],
      // leading: GestureDetector(
      //   onTap: () { /* Write listener code here */ },
      //   child: Icon(
      //     Icons.menu,  // add custom icons also
      //   ),
      // ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Solved partially modifing the code of the page.      return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       appBar: ReusableBar(),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your `ReusableBar` in the `title` property of `AppBar` it is wrapping an appbar inside another one. Like you mentionned in your comment you should implement your custom appbar like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: ReusableBar(),
   );
}
```

Doing like this you only declare one appbar, which should solve your issue.